# Multi Store - Multi User solution needed

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, multistore

I am looking for an extension/other kind of solution that would allow

1. Upon registration, for users to create a sub-store. (Or allow a parent-store admin to deploy a sub store on behalf of the user). The sub-store would need to be on a different domain.
2. The sub-store would have all (or part) of the products in the parent-store. If choosing specific products is difficult, then all products is acceptable.
3. Registered users can only access their sub store. See orders and customers only within and for their own sub-store
4. Users can modify some content in their sub store (about us, contact us, front page header, slide/banner should be changed etc).
5. Payments: Option 1: Payment gateway separate for each sub store (different Paypal email, pay by bank transfer to a different account etc). Option 2 (less preferred): Payment gateway the same across all sub-stores and goes to the same account.
6. Regardless of the payment option, each sub store would have multiple currencies available.
7. Products in the sub-store are the same as the main store but with an increase cost (by applying a margin as a global percentage e.g. everything is 35% more expensive than the main store etc).
8. Specific pricing can be set on a product by product basis (nice to have feature but not a must).
9. Shipping - no special requirement. Shipping for all sub-stores will be done from a central warehouse in Asia.
10. Emailing customers will be done from the domain of the sub-store.
11. The user cannot alter their sub-store aside from defining content, payment gateway and setting the margin.

Can anyone help with an idea?

Comment: Hi @ami, did you find any solution for that purposes? I need the same thing that you want.Thx