# Multi-store: Stores inherit global products

Tags: module, multistore

I saw a [similar question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60584/multi-store-multi-user-solution-needed) which was closed due to being "to broad," so I'm really hoping my is more specific/simple. In short, I'm in need of a multi-store solution/module which allows the concept of "global products," where each store can only inherit them with certain customizations – pricings, coupons, inventory etc – and not add new ones.

So, is there a module available for this requirement? Apparently [Marketplace](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace.html) doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

Every magento installation can have multiple websites. Each website contains your assortment of products etc. Each website can contain multiple store views. A store view is usually used to create multi-language web stores.

You can simply add new websites to magento and use the same root category for the new website so it has all the same products, or create a new root category so you can include part of the available products in that root category.

You can then set a different settings for products and shipping etc per website of even per store. Everything except the inventory. The inventory is used across the entire Magento installation and can not be split up in the normal installation.

However there do exist (shareware) extensions which make multi-warehouse and multi-inventory possible.